# Change Background of Listview to Parent Background? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, background-color

Is there A way I could change the background color of a listview to the color of the parent windows form? Thanks.

Comment: The listview? Or the listview items?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The listview itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try subclassing ListView and use it with your control, with the following in the initialiser:

`SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);`

Otherwise, you could have a reference to your ListView object, and explicitly set the background colour in your form code.

`myListView.BackColor = this.BackColor`

Comment: @TaW the bottom option... It sets the listview to the color of your form, so it worked with my setup where i change themes